# by() giving error when applying mean function over a data frame. What's happening?

Tags: r, mean, na

I am trying to learn `by()` in R(3.0.1) . 
This is what I am doing.

1. Open R
2. `attach(iris)`
3. `head(iris)`
4. `by(iris[,1:4] , Species , mean)`

This is what I am getting

```
> by(iris[,1:4] , Species , mean)

Species: setosa
[1] NA
------------------------------------------------------------ 
Species: versicolor
[1] NA
------------------------------------------------------------ 
Species: virginica
[1] NA
Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(data[x, , drop = FALSE], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

2: In mean.default(data[x, , drop = FALSE], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

3: In mean.default(data[x, , drop = FALSE], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Comment: @Momo `iris[1:4]` *isn't* a factor. `iris$Species` *is* a factor, but then that is what the `INDICES` argument wants (or is one of the options).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem here is that the function you are applying doesn't work on a data frame. In effect you are calling something like this

```
R> mean(iris[iris$Species == "setosa", 1:4])
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(iris[iris$Species == "setosa", 1:4]) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

i.e. you are passing a data frame of 4 columns, containing the rows of the original where `Species == "setosa"`.

For `by()` you need to do this variable by variable, as in

```
R> by(iris[,1] , iris$Species , mean)
iris$Species: setosa
[1] 5.006
------------------------------------------------------------ 
iris$Species: versicolor
[1] 5.936
------------------------------------------------------------ 
iris$Species: virginica
[1] 6.588
```

Or use `colMeans()` instead of `mean()` as the `FUN` applied

```
R> by(iris[,1:4] , iris$Species , colMeans)
iris$Species: setosa
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
       5.006        3.428        1.462        0.246 
------------------------------------------------------------ 
iris$Species: versicolor
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
       5.936        2.770        4.260        1.326 
------------------------------------------------------------ 
iris$Species: virginica
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
       6.588        2.974        5.552        2.026
```

If a canned function like `colMeans()` doesn't exist, then you can always write a wrapper, to `sapply()` eg

```
foo <- function(x, ...) sapply(x, mean, ...)
by(iris[, 1:4], iris$Species, foo)

R> by(iris[, 1:4], iris$Species, foo)
iris$Species: setosa
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
       5.006        3.428        1.462        0.246 
------------------------------------------------------------ 
iris$Species: versicolor
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
       5.936        2.770        4.260        1.326 
------------------------------------------------------------ 
iris$Species: virginica
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
       6.588        2.974        5.552        2.026
```

You might find `aggregate()` more appealing:

```
R> with(iris, aggregate(iris[,1:4], list(Species = Species), FUN = mean))
     Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1     setosa        5.006       3.428        1.462       0.246
2 versicolor        5.936       2.770        4.260       1.326
3  virginica        6.588       2.974        5.552       2.026
```

Notice how I use `with()` to access `Species` directly; this is much better than `attaching()` `iris` if you don't want to index via `iris$Species`.

Comment: Hey thanks for replying. But i was following a blog post over by() and was following the steps. I did the same and was constantly getting an error. And in the documentation of by() regarding the data input, it says "data-- an R object, normally a data frame, possibly a matrix." Even the example provided below seems to be applying the way i tried to apply on iris data set. The blog i was reading on is here : http://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2010/08/20/a-brief-introduction-to-apply-in-r/ Can you tell me why the implementation of by() in blog doesn't give error ??

Comment: @lovekesh `mean()` was changed not too long ago so that it would **not** work on a data frame - as that post is over 3 years old, I am not surprised that it no longer works. `mean()` (and `sd()`) were changed to make the language more consistent; it is easy to write `sapply(foo, mean)` to get the old behaviour (or faster is `colMeans()`) and there are a number of similar functions to `mean()` and `sd()` that **didn't** work on a data frame (they needed to be applied).

Comment: Thanks Gavin for the info and for replies. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more solution which combines "split" and "sapply".  The result is the same but transposed. Maybe this is preferable when statistics for many variables are shown because they are listed vertically.

> sapply(split(iris, iris[, 5]), function(x) colMeans(x[,c(1:4)]))

```
                setosa versicolor virginica
   Sepal.Length  5.006      5.936     6.588
   Sepal.Width   3.428      2.770     2.974
   Petal.Length  1.462      4.260     5.552
   Petal.Width   0.246      1.326     2.026
```